# Having trouble keeping Drop Down Menu Centered when resizing browser

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, browser

So, I'm having trouble with when I am running my page and resizing the browser / on mobile the drop down menu becomes uncentered and runs off the page. I think I have to fix my padding levels but I am not sure where and when I have, it has messed up more than what I was fixing.

Any help, helps!

[image: Normal Sized]
[image: When Resized]

[

```js
$('.drop-down').click(function() {
     $(this).hide();
 });
 $('.nav-main li').click(function() {
     $('.drop-down').hide();
 });
 //drop down slide down
  $('.nav-main li ul').hide().removeClass('.drop-down');
  $('.nav-main li').hover(
   function openDrop() {
     $('ul', this).stop().slideDown(900);
  }, function closeDrop() {
     $('ul', this).stop().slideUp(1000);
  });
```

```css
.nav-main {
 position: absolute;
 top: 0;
 height: 65px;
 width: 100%;
 text-align: center;
}
.nav-main ul {
 position: relative;
 margin: 0 auto;
 padding: 0;
 list-style: none;
 font-size: 22px;
 line-height: 100%;
 font-family: 'Futura W01 Bold', sans-serif;
 text-align: center;
 text-transform: uppercase;
 display: inline-block;
 width: 100%;
}
.nav-top {
 position: relative;
 margin: 0;
 padding: 0 66px 0 50px;
 float: none;
 display: inline-block;
 list-style: none;
}
.nav-top:first-child {
 padding-left: 0;
}
.nav-top:last-child {
 background-image: none;
 padding-right: 0;
}
.nav-top:last-child:after {
 content: none;
}
.nav-top > a {
 position: relative;
 display: block;
 margin: 0;
 color: #6f6f6f;
 text-decoration: none;
 padding-top: 20px;
 padding-bottom: 5px;
 -moz-transition: all 0.3s ease;
 -ms-transition: all 0.3s ease;
 -o-transition: all 0.3s ease;
 transition: all 0.3s ease;
}
.nav-top a:hover,
.nav-top.active > a {
 color: #454545;
 border-bottom: 4px solid #00e9d9;
 text-decoration: none;
}
.nav-top ul {
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
  left: -8.75px;
  width: 105%;
  top: calc(100% - 1px);
  border-bottom-left-radius: .3em;
  border-bottom-right-radius: .3em;

}
.nav-top:hover ul {
  position: absolute;
  top: calc(100% - 1px);
  left: -8.75px;
  width: 105%;

}
.nav-top li {
  float: center; 
  background-color: #e9e9e9;
  padding-top: 16px;
  padding-bottom: 10px;
  text-align: inherit;
}
.nav-top li:last-child {
 padding-bottom: 16px;
 border-bottom-left-radius: .3em;
    border-bottom-right-radius: .3em;
}
.nav-top li > a {
 position: relative;
 display: inline;
 margin: 0;
 color: #6f6f6f;
 text-decoration: none;
 padding-top: 20px;
 padding-bottom: 1px;
 -moz-transition: all 0.3s ease;
 -ms-transition: all 0.3s ease;
 -o-transition: all 0.3s ease;
 transition: all 0.3s ease;

}
.nav-top:after {
    display: block;
    position: absolute;
    left: 100%;
    top: -17px;
    width: 22px;
    z-index: 1;
    transform: translateX(-50%);
    height: 100%;
    -ms-transform: translateX(-50%);
    -webkit-transform: translateX(-50%);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<nav class="nav-main" role="navigation">
      <ul>
       <li class="nav-top"><a href="#welcome">Welcome</a></li>
       <li class="nav-top"><a href="#about">About</a>
        <ul class="drop-down">
         <li class="nav-drop"><a href="#about">Services</a></li>
         <li class="nav-drop"><a href="#client">Clients</a></li>
         <li class="nav-drop"><a href="#press">Press</a></li>
         <li class="nav-drop"><a href="#leadership">Leadership</a></li>
         <li class="nav-drop"><a href="#twitter">Follow Us</a></li>
        </ul>
       </li>
       <li class="nav-top"><a href="#contact">Contact</a></li>
      </ul>
      <span class="nav-arrow"></span>
     </nav>
```

][3](https://jsfiddle.net/jandrews96/3nrpz13v/)

Comment: Looks like you might need a media query at a certain breakpoint to reduce your menu font-size

Comment: How would one do that? And could you explain what it would do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can a `@media` breakpoint to target a certain browser width in order to reduce the font-size for the menu for the now smaller screen size.

```
@media only screen and (max-width: 767px) {
  .nav-main ul {
    font-size: 18px;
  }
}
```

[See this fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/3nrpz13v/1/) (reduce the frame window width to see the changes)

Of course the font-size and browser window threshold width are up to you and your needs. And you may want to change more the the font-size... like paddings for example.

Answer (score 0):

By using media queries you can fixed this problem, media query means you will define CSS according to the device screen size, you can learn more about [media query](https://responsivedesign.is/develop/browser-feature-support/media-queries-for-common-device-breakpoints) from this.

Answer (score 0):

While the other answers are correct in using a @media breakpoint I would also suggest using 'rem' units for sizes as opposed to "px". Working in relative units has several advantages